# How to export regression tree with two features as matrix?

Tags: python, r, matrix, tree, regression

I have a problem which is suitable for the application of a regression tree. The final result needs to be in matrix, though, not a tree. Is there an easy way in R or Python to export a regression tree which has only two features (in my case weight and distance) to a matrix where rows would be the weight classes, columns the distances and cell values the estimated prices? So far I could only find tree visualiziations as output.

I presume, that on each dimension, the tree distinguishes about 15 classes, so there are 200 to 300 cell values, in case this is important.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question (an example would be nice). But `rpart::rpart` returns (among other things) the number of observations per node, a data.frame with the names of the variables used in the split at each node and left and right split labels. I'm sure you could generate your data from this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you mean by "exporting the tree to a matrix"; I have no idea how a regression tree could be represented as a matrix. I guess you want to show the prediction of the tree for multiple combinations of your (two) features/input variables?

If so, you need first need to create all combinations of interest, e.g. by utilizing `grid.expand`. Then you put the resulting data.frame as `newdata` argument of the `predict` method of the tree to get the predicted outcome. Finally you `cast` the result into matrix form.